# How to prevent Windows 10 from stretching menu bitmaps

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, menu, win32gui

In my program I have a dynamically generated menu. It contains some text items with some text and some image items with dynamically generated bitmap images. The code that generates the menu looks like this:

```
hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_ADDDATA,_T("Add..."));
InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_SAVETOFILE, _T("Save..."));
InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_DOSOMETHING,
  _T("Some long long long long long long long long long long long menu item text..."));
int j= 0;
for(const auto& i : Data)
{
    HBITMAP hbm= CreateMenuBitmap(i,j++);  
    InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_BITMAP, IDM_DATA_START+j,(LPCTSTR)hbm);
}
```

The function `CreateMenuBitmap` generates the bitmap for a specified data item. The width of the bitmap depends on some things and can vary, as well as the width of the text menu items.

On windows 7 and 8 this worked fine (see the pictures):

[image: appearence on Windows 7]
[image]

But Windows 10 for some reason stretches the menu bitmap:
[image]

My question is: is it possible to bring back the old behavior without making `CreateMenuBitmap` OS-dependent and/or measuring all of the menu items? Maybe, there is some compatibility option, manifest value etc?

Comment: Maybe it's related to DPI Awareness. You can use APIs or manifests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-improvements-for-desktop-applications and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846517(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Setting DPI does not seem to affect this problem. I can reproduce this it with `LoadImage(NULL, L"*.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE)`(uses the actual resource size) + `InsertMenu`, But with `InsertMenuItem`, the hbitmap will be insert to the item icon position(left). This seems to be the current menu design: [Menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/cmd-menus)

Comment: Did you really wants to put the bitmap to the right side?

Comment: @Drake Wu - MSFT Yes, I do. The position at the left is too small for my purposes

Comment: Ok, I have submitted a issue internally, please continue to wait the subsequent updates here.

Comment: Hi @AVK, sorry for the delay, from internal engineer: *This has been fixed, and the fix will appear in the next major release of windows.*

Comment: @Drake Wu That's great. Thank you!